# OOP Select including a JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I've got this OOP Select I'm using and I want to add JOIN to the capabilities. My new code isn't producing an array though. Can anyone help?

Here's my initial simple Select which works like a dream

```
public function select($table, $rows = '*', $where = null, $order = null)
{
    $q = 'SELECT '.$rows.' FROM '.$table;
    if($where != null)
        $q .= ' WHERE '.$where;
    if($order != null)
        $q .= ' ORDER BY '.$order;

    $query = @mysql_query($q);
    if($query)
    {
        $this->numResults = mysql_num_rows($query);
        for($i = 0; $i < $this->numResults; $i++)
        {
            $r = mysql_fetch_array($query);
            $key = array_keys($r);
            for($x = 0; $x < count($key); $x++)
            {
                // Sanitizes keys so only alphavalues are allowed
                if(!is_int($key[$x]))
                {
                    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 1)
                        $this->result[$i][$key[$x]] = $r[$key[$x]];
                    else if(mysql_num_rows($query) < 1)
                        $this->result = null;
                    else
                        $this->result[$key[$x]] = $r[$key[$x]];
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And this is my attempt at adding a way for using join but it's returning no arrays.

```
public function select($table, $rows = '*', $join = null, $where = null, $order = null){
    // Create query from the variables passed to the function
    $q = 'SELECT '.$rows.' FROM '.$table;
    if($join != null){
        $q .= ' JOIN '.$join;
    }
    if($where != null){
        $q .= ' WHERE '.$where;
    }
    if($order != null){
        $q .= ' ORDER BY '.$order;
    }
    // Check to see if the table exists
    if($this->tableExists($table)){
        // The table exists, run the query
        $query = @mysql_query($q);
        if($query){
            // If the query returns >= 1 assign the number of rows to numResults
            $this->numResults = mysql_num_rows($query);
            // Loop through the query results by the number of rows returned
            for($i = 0; $i < $this->numResults; $i++){
                $r = mysql_fetch_array($query);
                $key = array_keys($r);
                for($x = 0; $x < count($key); $x++){
                    // Sanitizes keys so only alphavalues are allowed
                    if(!is_int($key[$x])){
                        if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 1){
                            $this->result[$i][$key[$x]] = $r[$key[$x]];
                        }else if(mysql_num_rows($query) < 1){
                            $this->result = null;
                        }else{
                            $this->result[$key[$x]] = $r[$key[$x]];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return true; // Query was successful
        }else{
            array_push($this->result,mysql_error());
            return false; // No rows where returned
        }
    }else{
        return false; // Table does not exist
    }
}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: What's OOP about this?

Comment: Have you checked your query??.try echo $query; and execute to check whether the query is correct or not

Comment: @MadaraUchiha thanks for that. Missed that completely.

Comment: why don't you use PDO which has already OOP built-in?

Answer (score 4):

if you are calling this function, you should declare it like this:

```
public function select($table, $rows, $where, $order)
{
        // your statements
}
```

then call it like this:

```
select('your_table','rows_you_want_select','where_conditions','column_you_want_to_sort');
```

On the other hand, If you are trying to put join statement, declare it like this:

```
public function select($table, $rows, $join, $where, $order)
    {
            // your statements
    }
```

then call it like this:

```
select('your_table','rows_you_want_select','join_conditions','where_conditions','column_you_want_to_sort');
```

Example:

```
select('table1','id',' table2 on table1.id = table2.id','id = 1','id');
```

You still have a lot to learn about [FUNCTIONAL PROGRAMMING](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) and please avoid using `mysql_`. Instead use `mysqli_` or `PDO`. If you really are after OOP then I strongly suggest [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).